# ajax response always go in else part

Tags: php, ajax

I am stuck with ajax response, that always go in else part and it print no in session's class called statusmsg and also add meta tag.
It is fine in localhost but not in live site.

Output:

```
<div class="statusmsg">
Welcome
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
no
</div>
```

Here is my login code with ajax jquery

```
      $.ajax({             
                    type: "POST",  
                    url:"scripts/ajax_login.php",  
                    data:"account="+account+"&pswd="+password,

                    beforeSend: function()
                    {
                        $(".login_result").show();
                    },
                    success: function(resp)
                    {  

                        if($.trim(resp) == 'no')
                        {   
                            $(".warn_msg").html("Wrong Username/Email And/or Passwrd");
                            return false;                               
                        }
                        else
                        {   
                            $(".statusmsg").html("Welcome "+$.trim(resp));
                            $(".loginArea").hide();
                            $(".sh_logout").show();                                                     
                        }
                    }, 

                    complete: function()
                    {
                        $(".login_result").hide();
                    },

                    error: function(e)
                    {  
                    alert('Error: ' + e);  
                    }  

               }); //end Ajax   

                   }//else   
              return true;
               }//function

=========================================
ajax_login.php

session_start();

include(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))."/includes/config.php");

$account  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['account']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['pswd']));

$sql = (strpos($account,'@')===false)?"SELECT * FROM register_members WHERE username = '".$account."' AND password = '".$password."'":"SELECT * FROM register_members WHERE password = '".$password."' AND email = '".$account."' ";

$qry = mysql_query($sql);
$msg = mysql_num_rows($qry); //returns 0 if not already exist
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry);


if(!$msg > 0)
{   
    echo trim('no');
}
else
{
$_SESSION['user'] = $row['username'];       
$user = trim($_SESSION['user']);
echo trim($user);   
}
```

Comment: first see what is coming in `resp` using `console.log(resp)`

Comment: To me this looks weird: `if(!$msg > 0) {`. Basically if your `$msg` is 0, it becomes 1 and vice versa... Put the ! outside of the brackets.

Comment: if user enter wrong username and password then it print no else name of user but wher user enter wrong username and password it still show no in statusmessage in session like welcome no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(!$msg > 0)
{   
    echo trim('no');
}
```

Should be

```
if !($msg > 0)
{   
    echo trim('no');
}
```

Else you are negating the value in $msg. If this is 0 it becomes 1 and if it's 1 it becomes 0. (Basic negation of a boolean value).

So neither 1 nor 0 will ever be bigger than 0 and thus it will never `echo trim('no');`.

But basically you can just check if `$msg` equals to zero like:

```
if ($msg == 0) {
   echo trim('no');
}
else {

}
```

Comment: it is giving error in cs5 dreamweaver to enter ! outside the bracets  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '!', expecting '(' in E:\wamp\www\php_site\scripts\ajax_login.php on line

Comment: Eh.. Post your code please. Shouldn't happen. But basically you can also do an equal to comparison. Check my answer.

Comment: it is fine on localhost but in live site it still giving no and extra meta tag                    <div class="statusmsg">
Welcome
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
no
</div>